# Entering special characters the same way on Windows and Linux

Tags: windows, keyboard, unicode, special-characters, compose-key

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> followed by the hex value of a Unicode character enters that character. For example, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> enters 'A', whose value is 0x41 in hex and 65 in decimal.

There's also the compose key, which lets you enter digraphs (e.g. <kbd>*compose key*</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>^</kbd> produces 'ê').

Unfortunately, neither of these works similarly to alt codes in Windows (where <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> produces 'A'). As a result, it's challenging to develop muscle memory.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: The first limit is typically the brain memory limit to memorize dozens of unicode values for all accented chars, so the compose key is the way to go. To develop the according muscle memory, see https://superuser.com/questions/64178/compose-key-on-windows for how solutions to add compose key to windows.

Comment: @Philippos-prostrike- I'm okay with memorizing 12 unicode values (it's all my language uses), but it sounds like setting up the compose key is the best solution anyway. I would accept your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install a Compose Key utility on your Windows system. That's my preferred approach as I can create the same custom key combinations on my Linux-based and Windows platforms.

My preferred solution used to be [AllChars](http://allchars.zwolnet.com/) ([Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/allchars/)) but as it no longer works reliably on Windows 10 et seq, I moved to [WinCompose](http://wincompose.info/) ([README](https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose#readme)) about six months ago.

As this is a Windows solution rather than a Linux/UNIX one I'll not go into more detail here, but suffice to say it works very well.

Answer (score 2):

If the ability to enter a limited set of accented characters satisfies your needs *and* you are OK with the US keyboard layout, there is a method that is common to Linux and Windows: the [US International keyboard layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY#US-International). With this layout you enter accented characters directly using the right Alt key as an extra shift key. This is of course not a general solution for entering any Unicode character, since it only supports a fixed set of characters.